# Format Date with fmt:formatDate JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to format a date with:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${newsletter.createdOn}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
```

newsletter is an object with a `createdOn` property which is `java.util.Date`.

When I invoke the previous sentence I get:

According to the TLD, the attribute value does not accept expressions.

I am importing fmt with

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Does anyone know how can I work around this problem?

I am using the jstl.jar coming with tomcat.

Under jstl.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF stays:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.5.3 
Created-By: 1.4.2-b28 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Specification-Title: JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL)
Specification-Version: 1.1
Implementation-Title: JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library API Refere
 nce Implementation
Implementation-Version: 1.1.0-D13
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.sun
Extension-Name: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl
```

I am using Apache Tomcat Version 6.0.14

Comment: Formatting your date as "MM/dd/yyyy" is evil :) Use MMM dd yyyy instead, where MMM is the name of the month. Otherwise a date of say 1/6/2009 will leave have of your potential audience thinking it was published on the 1st June.

Comment: Do you know what version fo Tomcat you're running?

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. Have you done a clean build, shutdown, deleted %TOMCAT_HOME%\work, restarted and redeployed to make sure nothing's sticking around?

Comment: A clean build, shutdown, deleted %TOMCAT_HOME%\work, restarted and redeployed does not Help.

Comment: You didn't switch back to the 1.0 declaration, did you?

Answer (score 41):

Try

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Comment: The difference is the .../jsp/... part of the uri.

Answer (score 5):

[This guy](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=209779) seems to have worked around the problem by extracting the TLD from the jar, modifying it, placing it in the WAR's WEB-INF directory, and adding an entry to his `web.xml` like this:

```
<jsp-config>
 <taglib>
  <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt</taglib-uri>
  <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
 </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

In the end, he switched to the 1.1 declaration:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"/>
```

Comment: Actually, only fixing the taglib URI was sufficient. Hassling with loose TLDs is a big myth and should really not be done.

Comment: The "This guy" link is broken

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue.

I Changed 
<%@ taglib  prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/**fmt**" %>
to
<%@ taglib  prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/**fmt_rt**" %>
and it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not using the runtime versions of the tag lib? May we see the library import statement?

I think [lucus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281380/format-date-with-fmtformatdate-jsp#281422) is onto something, according to this [FAQ](http://faq.javaranch.com/java/JstlTagLibDefinitions) on JavaRanch, that's a JSTL 1.0 declaration. You might want to update to 1.1.

What's your environment, app server, and version?

Comment: Do you know what version you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JSTL 1.0 or 1.1? formatDate in 1.1 should accept expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, i needed 1.1 but i had to change the library import statements for both c and fmt.
Now it works. Thanks for the help, and sorry for the confusion.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It just worked for me by adding "_rt" to taglib url like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt_rt" %>
```

I found it in [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211.html)

have fun!

Comment: You have an outdated JSTL version (that article is also old). Upgrade JSTL. Read [our JSTL wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `fmt-1_0-rt.tld` or `fmt-1_0.tld` taglib.

The difference is the settings for `rtexprvalue`

In one, this is false, in the other it is true.

Comment: No idea, how can i know this. I am using the jstl.jar where this tags are defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix='fmt'%>
```

is working for me.