# JSTL1.2 According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute var does not accept any expressions

Tags: java, maven, jstl, jsp-tags, tomcat8

I have been searching all over google for an answer and it doesn't work.

I am getting this error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/calendarEntry.jsp (line: 5, column: 46) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute var does not accept any expressions

Here's my jsp file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <c:set var="eventDate" value="${calendarEntry.date}"/>
    <h1 class="page-header">Calendar Event on <fmt:formatDate value="date" var="${eventDate}" /></h1>
```

The error is happening at the last line. fmt

Web App declartion

```
<web-app version="3.1"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
```

Maven Depedencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Deployment Environment - Tomcat 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for helping everyone. I realised it was a stupid mistake from my side..

Instead of

```
<fmt:formatDate value="date" var="${eventDate}" />
```

It should be

```
<fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${calendarEntry.date}"
```

Comment: Would sure help if you left comment before down voting.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem, and this answer points to basically trying two different taglib declarations.  Perhaps try both of them?

[Format Date with fmt:formatDate JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281380/format-date-with-fmtformatdate-jsp)

Switching to the taglib you have declared in your jsp file solved my problem, ironically.

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

vs

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<fmt:formatDate value="date" var="${eventDate}" />
```

Switch value and var.

```
<fmt:formatDate var="date" value="${eventDate}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans it does not create a web.xml file automatically now.(previously in j2ee it was created. it is optional for some cases.I face the same issue  with the jstl remove attribute and after I created the web.xml file the issue was gone.but corrected one is a new project

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

Change the above to:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue. I changed Tomcat version to- apache-tomcat-7.0.39 instead of -apache-tomcat-7.0.54 from SERVER- Runtime Environment